# How to use "needs" with nested routes / controllers in emberjs RC 2

Tags: ember.js

I have a very basic route setup that allows me to first show "all" records for some object. Then if the user selects a dropdown they can filter this down using a date.

I recently upgraded to RC2 and realized that "needs" has replaced or will soon replace controllerFor.

I'm curious how I can use "needs" in the below situation where I need the nested / inner route for "records.date" to change the content for the parent "records" route when a date is selected.

What is missing from below is that inside the App.RecordsDateRoute I need to change the content of the "records" controller to be a new filter (by date this time) and everything I seem to do just dumps the handlebars template and show nothing -even when I try to use something simple like

```
this.controllerFor("records").set('content', App.Record.find(new Date(model.loaded)))
```

from within the setupController method of the RecordsDateRoute

```
App.Router.map(function(match) {
  return this.resource("records", { path: "/" }, function() {
    return this.route("date", { path: "/:date_loaded" });
  });
});

App.RecordsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  selected: 0,
  dates: Ember.computed(function() {
    return App.Date.find();
  }).property()
});

App.RecordsIndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    this.controllerFor("records").set("selected", 0);
    return App.Record.find();
  }
});

App.RecordsDateRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params) {
    //the controllerFor below seems to be working great ... but what about needs?
    this.controllerFor("records").set("selected", params.date_loaded);
    return App.Date.create({ loaded: params.date_loaded });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

With rc2, instances of other controllers can be retrieved via "controllers.controllerName", in you case it would be `this.get('controllers.records')`.

The "needs" declaration makes the referencing controller sort of import the reference to the other controller; in your case, the date controller would be:

```
App.RecordsDateRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  needs: ['records'],
  model: function(params) {
    this.get("controllers.records").set("selected", params.date_loaded);
    return App.Date.create({ loaded: params.date_loaded });
  }
});
```

Regarding `App.Record.find(new Date(model.loaded))`, find() expects an id or an object whose keys and values will be used to filter the collection of models, but you're giving it a Javascript date.

Did you mean `App.Record.find(new App.Date(model.loaded))`, or maybe something like `App.Record.find({ loaded: model.loaded }) /* assuming it's already a Date */`?

There is also an `initController(controller, model)` method in the route called , maybe you could use that instead of "overloading" the model() method with too many responsibilities. http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#method_setupController

Comment: I have somewhat related question involving loading dates from nested routes and I have placed a bounty of **50 points** incase any one wants to check it out: **http://bit.ly/15YQscl**.  Many thanks.

Comment: but here you used `needs:` in a route. So then does the route then get access to the `records` controller properties or `records` route properties? Does including a controller mean you get its controller properties and route properties?

Answer (score 2):

> I recently upgraded to RC2 and realized that "needs" has replaced or will soon replace controllerFor.

To access another controller from route hooks you should continue to use `controllerFor`. `Controller.needs` is for communication between controllers, it replaces the now deprecated use of `controllerFor` method on controllers. AFAIK there is no plan to deprecate controllerFor on ember Routes.

> I'm curious how I can use "needs" in the below situation where I need the nested / inner route for "records.date" to change the content for the parent "records" route when a date is selected.

For this use case it would be best to stick with controllerFor. It is possible to use needs this way, by specifying that `App.RecordsDateController needs = ['records']` you could access the records controller via `controller.get('controllers.records')` from within your route's `setupController` hook.

> What is missing from below is that inside the App.RecordsDateRoute I need to change the content of the "records" controller to be a new filter (by date this time) and everything I seem to do just dumps the handlebars template and show nothing -even when I try to use something simple like `this.controllerFor("records").set('content', App.Record.find(new Date(model.loaded)))` from within the setupController method of the RecordsDateRoute

```
App.RecordsDateRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params) {
    return App.Date.create({ loaded: params.date_loaded });
  },
  setupController: function(controller, model) {
    var recordsController = this.controllerFor("records");
    // Moved this from model hook, since here you are 'setting up a controller'
    recordsController.set("selected", model.date_loaded);
    // Set query based on current route's model
    var query = { loaded: model.loaded };
    recordsController.set("content", App.Record.find(query));
  }
});
```